# IE9 SCRIPT87: Invalid argument on XDomainRequest

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, explorer, xdomainrequest

I'm testing my app on Internet Explorer 9, the app works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, but in IE.... 
Well, in this code:

```
this.xhr.open("PUT",url,true);
```

The IE says 'SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.' i attach an image:
[image]

The xhr element is a XDomainRequest() object, the url attribute is a correct url. Anybody knows what are IE9 talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i thought that my app with cross origin request that uses an api restful (with get, post, put and delete methods) will be 'compatible' with IE (obviusly with 8 and 9 versions), i thought the XDomainRequest had the same implementation of cors than XMLHttpRequest, but no farther, with XDomainRequest we have a lot of restrictions how: only 'get' and 'post' methods run, no customize headers, etc. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) a link with this issues of ie8 and 9.

Appears the ie10 will have a cors implementation with XMLHttpRequest.